# Where can i find VMARGS in IBM WAS 8.5

Tags: websphere

I have installed IBM WAS 8.5 During startup I can see in the console

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<verbosegc xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/j9/verbosegc" version="R26_Java626_SR2_20120322_1722_B106210_CMPRSS">
<initialized id="1" timestamp="2016-07-26T11:55:01.392">
  <attribute name="gcPolicy" value="-Xgcpolicy:gencon" />
  <attribute name="maxHeapSize" value="0x60000000" />
  <attribute name="initialHeapSize" value="0x60000000" />
  <attribute name="compressedRefs" value="true" />
  <attribute name="compressedRefsDisplacement" value="0x0" />
  <attribute name="compressedRefsShift" value="0x0" />
  <attribute name="pageSize" value="0x1000" />
  <attribute name="requestedPageSize" value="0x1000" />
  <attribute name="gcthreads" value="12" />
  <attribute name="numaNodes" value="0" />
  <system>
    <attribute name="physicalMemory" value="17100500992" />
    <attribute name="numCPUs" value="12" />
    <attribute name="architecture" value="amd64" />
    <attribute name="os" value="Windows 7" />
    <attribute name="osVersion" value="6.1" />
  </system>
  <vmargs>
    <vmarg name="-Xoptionsfile=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin\compressedrefs\options.default" />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:mode=default,noLockword=java/lang/String,noLockword=java/util/MapEntry,noLockword=java/util/HashMap$Entry,noLockword..." />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:noLockword=java/lang/invoke/MethodType" />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:noLockword=java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle" />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:noLockword=java/lang/invoke/CollectHandle" />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ConstructorHandle" />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ConvertHandle" />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ArgumentConversionHandle" />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:noLockword=java/lang/invoke/AsTypeHandle" />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ExplicitCastHandle" />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:noLockword=ja
```

….rest is removed for brevity.

Where these vmargs are set and in which file ? I need to edit one of vmarg.

Thanks Scott.I got in to an issue like below.

There is missing  ‘=’ i.e equal sign between the key and value

```
…..
<vmarg name="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\EbodsMavenSpringWS/properties/wsjaas...." />
    <vmarg name="-Djava.security.policyC:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\EbodsMavenSpringWS/properties/server.policy" />                                       <vmarg name="-Dsun.java.command=com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher -nosplash -application com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher com.ibm.ws.runt..." />
    <vmarg name="-Dsun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD" />
    <vmarg name="_port_library" value="000007FEF4267A40" />
    <vmarg name="_bfu_java" value="000007FEF4268FD8" />
    <vmarg name="_org.apache.harmony.vmi.portlib" value="00000000002C0930" />
  </vmargs>
</initialized>


Insufficient Java 2 security permissions to start the process!
java.security.policy = null
CodeSource for bootstrap.jar = ProtectionDomain
CodeSource=CodeSource, url=file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar, <no certificates>
ClassLoader=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c630ab9f
<no principals>
```

Comment: Google "websphere jvm arguments"

Comment: Some how my jvm arguments are messed up as there is '=' equal sign between policy and C:\  <vmarg name="-Djava.security.policyC:\Program Files (x86)\IB

Answer (score 0):

The file you're looking for is `server.xml`. You can find this inside your configuration folder, at the following location.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\EbodsMavenSpringWS\config\cells\<CELL_NAME>\nodes\<NODE_NAME>\servers\<SERVER_NAME>\server.xml
```

Open up `server.xml` using a text editor, and find the 'jvmEntries' id. It should like the example given below.

`<jvmEntries xmi:id="JavaVirtualMachine_1183122130078" verboseModeClass="false" verboseModeGarbageCollection="true" verboseModeJNI="false" initialHeapSize="1280" maximumHeapSize="2048" runHProf="false" hprofArguments="" debugMode="false" debugArgs="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777" genericJvmArguments="-Xdisableexplicitgc -Djava.awt.headless=true">
</jvmEntries>`

Your JVM arguments should be listed under the `genericJvmArguments` section. Modify the values and start the server.

Additional note: As you have installed WAS to the 'Program Files (x86)' folder, you will need an account with administrator privileges to run the server.